# Setting the size of the operating system's receive buffer for an ipv4.PacketConn

Tags: go

I used to read and write `UDP` messages using a `net.UDPConn` where I could use `SetReadBuffer` to change the OS's receive buffer size.

As I need to be able to set the `TTL` on the `UDP` packets that my application is sending I am moving to the [`ipv4`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4) package where I have more low level access to IP sockets and I can set the `TTL` for outgoing messages.

But I have no clue on how to change the read buffer size on an [`ipv4.PacketConn`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4#PacketConn).

The implementation of [`SetReadBuffer`](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=8733:8778#L258) sets the buffer using the file descriptor of the connection is something like this possible with an `ipv4.PacketConn`?

Comment: I guess one way to solve this is by changing the default buffer size on the host machine. Its quite common that the default and max sizes are set at the same value and changing the size programmatically using `SetReadBuffer` has only effect the size is set to a smaller value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it on golang 1.11 and up on a unix platform:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "syscall"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func control(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
    c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        if err := unix.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), unix.SOL_SOCKET, unix.SO_RCVBUF, 1024*1024); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Set socket receive buffer size failed: %v\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Set socket receive buffer size\n")
    })
    return nil
}


func main() {
    lc := net.ListenConfig{Control: control}
    if _, err := lc.ListenPacket(context.Background(), "udp", "127.0.0.1:9999"); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ListenPacket failed: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

[Golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/r1w-1In7SLV).